# Joomla - menu item showing different category in different columns

Tags: layout, joomla, categories

i like to have a layout similar to the "Category blog" but showing for example in 3 different column 3 different category. One column for each category.

Example:

category 1 article 1 | category 2 article 1 | category 3 article 1
category 1 article 2 | category 2 article 2 | category 3 article 2
category 1 article 3 | category 2 article 3 | category 3 article 3

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would look at the [news section](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/news-display) of the Joomla! Extension Directory a couple of the sub-sections like "[Articles Showcase](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/news-display/articles-display/articles-showcase)" and "[Articles Listing](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/news-display/articles-display/articles-listing)" may be able to provide a solution for you.